# Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function when trying to use Max function with IF condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table category_model with columns- category_id, start_range, end_range and percentile.

`category_id` is of type `varchar` e.g. C1, C2, C3
`start_range` and `end_range` are `float` values e.g. -0.25 to 4.65

I am trying to check for scores that fall within a certain range and return the corresponding percentile.

The following query returns an error code 1111-invalid use of group function-

```
SELECT max(IF(spm.start_range <= 1.19 AND spm.end_range >= 1.19, spm.percentile, IF(max(spm.end_range) < 1.19, 99, 0))) AS percentile
FROM category_model spm
WHERE spm.category_id = 'C1'
```

If I replace it with the query below, it works fine, but then I cannot check the boundary conditions(e.g. a score falls outside the min start_range or max end_range).

```
SELECT max(IF(spm.start_range <= 1.19 AND spm.end_range >= 1.19, spm.percentile, 0)) AS percentile
FROM category_model spm 
WHERE spm.category_id='C1'
```

Is there a way around this? I am using MySql version 5.2

Comment: Can you show us sample data along with the logic of your query?

Comment: What are the conditions on the second nested call to `MAX()` ?

Comment: I have added some more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple aggregate function combination is not allowed.

Try this one by using subquery:

```
SELECT max(IF(spm.start_range <= 1.19 AND spm.end_range >= 1.19, spm.percentile, IF((SELECT MAX(end_range) FROM category_model) < 1.19, 99, 0))) AS percentile
FROM category_model spm
WHERE spm.category_id = 'C1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `sub-query`;

```
SELECT 
    max(
        IF(
            spm.start_range <= 1.19 AND spm.end_range >= 1.19, 
            spm.percentile, 
            IF(x.max_end_range < 1.19, 99, 0)
        )
    ) AS percentile
FROM category_model spm
cross join (
    select max(end_range) max_end_range
    FROM category_model
    WHERE spm.category_id = 'C1'
) x
WHERE spm.category_id = 'C1'
```

Note:- Here `spm.category_id = 'C1'` condition is applied to calculate `max_end_range`
If that is not what you want then remove the condition.